# Show Two Buttons at Bottom in a ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity

I am using [this](http://envyandroid.com/creating-listdialog-with-images-and-text/) tutorial and successfully implemented a code to show Data in an Activity (in form of Dialog) which extends ListActivity

Still, I am getting Data in a below format by using a Dialog theme

[image]

Now, I would like to know, How Can I add two buttons at bottom ?

Just like We usually see in AlertDialog(s) : OK and CANCEL

**CountrycodeActivity.java:**

```
public class CountrycodeActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static String RESULT_CONTRYCODE = "countrycode";
    public String[] countrynames, countrycodes;
    private TypedArray imgs;
    private List<Country> countryList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        populateCountryList();
        ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter = new CountryListArrayAdapter(this, countryList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Country c = countryList.get(position);
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra(RESULT_CONTRYCODE, c.getCode());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                imgs.recycle(); //recycle images
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateCountryList() {
        countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
        countrynames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_names);
        countrycodes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_codes);
        imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.country_flags);
        for(int i = 0; i < countrycodes.length; i++){
            countryList.add(new Country(countrynames[i], countrycodes[i], imgs.getDrawable(i)));
        }
    }

    public class Country {
        private String name;
        private String code;
        private Drawable flag;
        public Country(String name, String code, Drawable flag){
            this.name = name;
            this.code = code;
            this.flag = flag;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public Drawable getFlag() {
            return flag;
        }
        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }
    }
}
```

**CountryListArrayAdapter.java:**

```
public class CountryListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CountrycodeActivity.Country> {

    private final List<CountrycodeActivity.Country> list;
    private final Activity context;

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView name;
        protected ImageView flag;
    }

    public CountryListArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<CountrycodeActivity.Country> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_countrycode_row, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_countrycode_row, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.flag.setImageDrawable(list.get(position).getFlag());
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this two lines in your listview

```
  android:layout_height="0sp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
```

and below your listview add this linear layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No it won't, if placed "below" the ListView.

Comment: add this below your listview not your list item xml

Comment: I am not using any ListView separately in an XML, check this code you will get more clearity about current structure of my code: http://envyandroid.com/creating-listdialog-with-images-and-text/

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you're using the `Dialog` interface, you can `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton` and set the click listeners accordingly.